# Do I misuse fwrite function?

Tags: c

I do not understand why the following code can create the aaa file, but cannot write '1' (the buffer value) into the aaa file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int buf;
    FILE *fp;

    buf = 1;
    a = 5;
    b = 6;
    fp = fopen("c:\\aaa.txt","wb");
    fwrite(&buf, sizeof(int),1,fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Check the return value of `fwrite`! Writing an integer in binary representation into a `.txt` file is probably not what you want. Maybe you just dont' *see* the character in the file because of that?

Comment: Good point there, ASCII for `1` is `SOH (start of heading)` probably not printable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call `fclose(fp)` or `fflush(fp)` to make sure content of file buffer gets flushed to the file.

Comment: Shouldn't the OS take care of that when the program terminates?

Comment: That is a fair question, I don't know why it does not do that.

Comment: denniston: Why would you want to introduce a dependency upon the operating system to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Add `fclose(fp);` before returning.